# MySQL Error on Mac Lion 10.7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion

I am trying to make mysql run on mac so I can make it work with rails 3. I installed the mysql*.dmg file from the official website, and I have also added this in my ".bashrc" file:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Now I have created a /tmp/mysql.lock file, changed its permission and I still get this error when I am trying to run mysql:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
```

Any help installing mysql on Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because MySQL is probably creating the socket file somewhere else. Use

```
mysqladmin variables
```

in the terminal to find out the exact location and use it in your `database.yaml`.